# How to sign (x.509) XML element?

Tags: c#, xml, x509certificate

I need sign a XML file with `X.509` certificate

In this moment I have (copy form msdn)

```
    public static void SignXml(XmlDocument xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 uidCert)
    {

        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)uidCert.PrivateKey;


        // Check arguments. 
        if (xmlDoc == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("xmlDoc");
        if (rsaKey == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Key");

        // Create a SignedXml object.
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

        // Add the key to the SignedXml document.
        signedXml.SigningKey = rsaKey;


        // Create a reference to be signed.
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.Uri = "";

        // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
        XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(env);

        // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);


        // Add an RSAKeyValue KeyInfo (optional; helps recipient find key to validate).
        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();

        KeyInfoX509Data clause = new KeyInfoX509Data();
        clause.AddSubjectName(uidCert.Subject);
        clause.AddCertificate(uidCert);
        keyInfo.AddClause(clause);
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

        // Compute the signature.
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

        // Get the XML representation of the signature and save 
        // it to an XmlElement object.
        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

        System.Console.WriteLine(signedXml.GetXml().InnerXml);

        // Append the element to the XML docu0ment.
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
```

When I run it this generate a file like

```
<root>
   <myelement>.....</myelement>
   <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
   ....
   </Signature>
   ....
```

**But the people who need this file tells me this wrong**, they need the file has signed `myelement` content

For exmaple they need the result file like this

```
<root>
   <myelement>
      <Signature>.....
      </Signature>
   </myelement>
</root>
```

how I do this?

Comment: http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/12/interoperable-xml-digital-signatures-c.html

Comment: Are you able to update your title? You're not signing an element. You're signing the document. Got my hopes up because there is an XmlElement constructor for SignedXml and I'm having problems there...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I modified a couple of lines at end of SignXml()

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            string input =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
                "<root></root>";

            doc.LoadXml(input);

            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates;

            SignXml(doc, certCollection[0]);
        }


        public static void SignXml(XmlDocument xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 uidCert)
        {

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)uidCert.PrivateKey;


            // Check arguments. 
            if (xmlDoc == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("xmlDoc");
            if (rsaKey == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Key");

            // Create a SignedXml object.
            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

            // Add the key to the SignedXml document.
            signedXml.SigningKey = rsaKey;


            // Create a reference to be signed.
            Reference reference = new Reference();
            reference.Uri = "";

            // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
            XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
            reference.AddTransform(env);

            // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
            signedXml.AddReference(reference);


            // Add an RSAKeyValue KeyInfo (optional; helps recipient find key to validate).
            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();

            KeyInfoX509Data clause = new KeyInfoX509Data();
            clause.AddSubjectName(uidCert.Subject);
            clause.AddCertificate(uidCert);
            keyInfo.AddClause(clause);
            signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

            // Compute the signature.
            signedXml.ComputeSignature();

            // Get the XML representation of the signature and save 
            // it to an XmlElement object.
            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

            System.Console.WriteLine(signedXml.GetXml().InnerXml);

            // Append the element to the XML docu0ment.
            XmlElement root = (XmlElement)xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("root")[0];
            XmlElement myElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("myelement");
            root.AppendChild(myElement);
            myElement.AppendChild(xmlDigitalSignature);
        }
    }
}
​
```